# SQL - Referencing a table at a specific position in content?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am not sure if this is possible, but I'm also not sure if I am using the correct terminology here, so forgive and correct me if I don't. Also, this question is more about database design more generally.

Say I have something like `Article`:

```
Title: Stem cells are soon being used for stuff
Text: "Here is the content for an article about stuff. Here is some more info on stemm cells and stuff. [To the uninitiated, here comes an Info Box on Stem Cells in general, you can expand it!] Now some more text about stem cells and stuff"
```

In my app I would like to display the article, and then at an exact position (here after sentence no. 2, but this will vary from article to article) insert an info-box on stem cells, which is in its own SQL table.

I know that the idea of SQL in general is that I reference `InfoBox` in my `Article` and simply point to it. That would be the relation between article and infoBox.

But how do I specify that `infoBox` should come exactly after Sentence No. 2? (as in the example). And this will not always be the case. Sometimes there might be no infoBox for an article or multiple, sometimes it will come after sentence no. 25 or 100 -etc.

I don't want to mix relations/fields and content, but I don't understand how I would realise something like this in SQL.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: We could give you more details if you gave us the DDL for the tables associated with this issue. PS Are Title & Text supposed to be columns of table Article? Are you only interested in base tables or are you interested in what you pass to your app?

Answer (score 1):

A table (base table or query result) holds rows of values that participate in a relation(ship)/association. Those are the rows that make the table's associated *(characteristic) predicate* (sentence template parameterized by column names) into a true *proposition* (statement).

You seem to want a base table for triples where

```
infoBox [i] should come exactly after Sentence No. [n] of article [a]
```

PS Time to read a published academic textbook on information modeling & database design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not textbooks on doing information modeling & database design.)